# Speech Enhancement Libraries

Tags: algorithms, sound, voice, enhancement

Is there any speech enhancement algorithm library?

I need to process a sound to voice recognition, and I want to remove noise from audio source.

Answer (score 1):

Nice a Brazilian Guy lol !

This is a little tricky to tell you without know what language are you working ...

Maybe a simple Filter can solve your problem or you can look at source code from Audacity are a cool code for noise removal.

Another choice is use [Sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html) by command line to process your voice and use noiseprof to try remove noise.

Comment: I believe sox is not a possible (we already use in other solutions), because this is a Android solution.
I found the Audacity code, but do you know here this type of filter is implemented there?

Comment: I have never been so deeply to know what Audacity use :-(, are you from Campinas me too !!

Answer (score 0):

[WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/) has an Android API with a very good noise suppresing module.